# How to calculate this percentage in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sum

I have two query:

```
SELECT SUM(column1) AS Result_All FROM table;
SELECT SUM(column1) AS Result_Something FROM table WHERE column2 LIKE '%something%';
```

The first one gives a sum of column 1.
Lets say the result is 10.000.

The second one gives a sum of column 1 where column2 is %something%.
Lets say the result is 2.000.

How can i make these two queries into 1 and calaculate how many percentage is query2 to query1?
If the two result is 10.000 and 2.000, the percentage should be 20%.

Edit: The 'AS' is not needed for me, i just wrote to help what it is.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method is conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN column2 LIKE '%something%' THEN column1 END) / SUM(column1) AS ratio
FROM table;
```

You can multiply by 100 if you want a number between 0 and 100 instead of 0 and 1.  Personally, I prefer a ratio.

Comment: @GMB . . . Down to the second.

Answer (score 1):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when column2 like '%something%' then column1 end) / sum(column1) ratio
from mytable
```

This gives you a decimal number from `0` to `1`, that you can multiply by `100` if you want a percentage.